# How to exceed 64 channels (bits) in this publishing system

Tags: php, mysql, performance, bit-manipulation

EDIT:

In the question below I simplified my problem so it was easy to explain.  I can see now, based on the first few comments, that I have oversimplified it.  So, when you read through, please keep in mind this new fact: there can be almost as many publishers in the system as there are users, and each publisher can have their own list (preferably thousands) of interest groups.  In short, please take it as a given that speed is important, and that simple lists just won't cut it...

END EDIT.

I am designing a system for publishing posts (blog-style articles) to users, using MySQL and PHP.  Posts are published to 'interest groups', and users sign-up to read particular interest groups.  When a user requests their news feed, I need to be able to assemble and return the list of articles as quickly as possible.

In the interests of speed, I am using bitwise operators to select posts from the database.  Each interest group corresponds to a bit in an integer.  Each post has a 'publishing mask', which is an integer storing the groups to which it is published.  Each user as a 'read mask', which is an integer storing the groups that the user is interested in.

By way of example, the interest groups might be as follows:

- bit 0 (decimal 1): Fishing
- bit 1 (decimal 2): Bush Walking
- bit 2 (decimal 4): Sky Diving

In this case, a post's publication mask might be, say '3' (Fishing and Bush Walking).  A user with a read mask of '5' (Fishing and Sky Diving) would have access to the article, but a user with a read mask of '4' would not.  The selection of posts happens within a SQL query.  The query simply uses a WHERE clause that returns the boolean result of a bitwise-AND between the user's read mask and the publication mask of each post.

So... this works really nicely, except for the obvious problem: I am limited to 64 interest groups.  For the life of me, I can't think of an elegant way around it.

I could add a second pair of masks and base the WHERE clause on `((PubMask1 AND ReadMask1) || (PubMask2 AND ReadMask2))` however this 'linear' approach gives me only 128 groups.  What if I want, say, 3000?

I looked at the PHP GMP library however that doesn't help - I don't want to have to pull everything from the database to filter it in PHP - and I can't find any GMP-equivalent as a MySQL plugin.  (Besides that, I'm not sure what the speed would be like for multiple precision libraries).

Are there any other possibilities that I am missing?  For example, is there a way to store a long, long string of zeros-and-ones and perform binary arithmetic on them?

One possible solution would be to use pairs of masks as above (PubMask1, PubMask2, ReadMask1, ReadMask2), and let each post record have multiple publication records (and each user have multiple read mask records).  In this case I could have up to 64 x 64 interest groups, but I really don't want to introduce one-to-many relationships into this high-performance scenario if I can help it.

Comment: so.....don't use a bitmask. use columns

Comment: _in the interests of speed_ - this is a micro-optimisation. The cost in performance is trivial by comparison with the cost in limited flexibility, as you have already found. The answer is simple - don't do it this way: use a list.

Comment: A properly indexed join column (or table) in SQL can do this very quickly (probably at the same speed in practical terms).

Comment: "In the interests of speed, I am using bitwise operators to select posts from the database." Those statements are contradictory. Bit masks are **brutally slow** in MySQL because they can't be indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're proposing here is going down a deep, deep rabbit hole and won't actually yield any performance improvements. In fact, it'll probably have the opposite effect, rendering your schema not just obnoxious to use, but crippled by performance problems due to your non-standard flagging approach. The more you go against the grain in an RDBMS like MySQL, the more you're punished with performance problems.

The by-the-book approach to this is to have a simple *association table* that links posts to groups:

```
CREATE TABLE post_group_links(
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  post_id INT NOT NULL,
  group_id INT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `index_pgl_post_group` (`post_id`,`group_id`)
);
```

That `UNIQUE` index constraint means you can have one and only one association between post and group. A database like MySQL makes it trivial and fast to fetch all articles for a group:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts
  LEFT JOIN post_group_links ON posts.id=post_id
  WHERE post_group_links.group_id=?
```

That should run in milliseconds for even large databases because the index will take care of it. If you want to order these posts you may need to add some kind of ordering data to the join table, but that's trivial to add and incorporate into the index.

If you want to find posts in more than one group using an exclusive `AND` it's possible as well, though slower, with something roughly like the following:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts
  LEFT JOIN post_group_links ON posts.id=post_id
  WHERE post_group_links.group_id IN (?,?,?)
  GROUP BY posts.id
  HAVING COUNT(post_group_links.id)=3
```

There's many ways to write that, including using a sub-query if that makes it easier to follow.

This will easily scale to millions of posts in thousands of groups. A modern SSD-backed MySQL server won't even break a sweat running queries like that thousands of times a minute, and can be tuned to run even faster using more advanced techniques like partitioning or horizontal sharding.

Your proposed solution involving a handful of 64-bit columns is in direct violation of the important [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule). Columns like `PubMask1`, `PubMask2` are almost *always* a sure sign of a schema with fundamental design problems.